# Calculate pandas dataframe column not using for loops

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
Date        Open    High to Low   X
27-Feb-15   A           P         x1
26-Feb-15   B           Q         x2
25-Feb-15   C           R         x3
24-Feb-15   D           S         x4
```

i need to calculate X column values like follows,

```
x1 = (P+Q)/B
x2 = (Q+R)/C
   '
   '
```

is there any way to do this not using for loops using pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Rolling.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html) with division by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
print (df)
        Date  Open  High to Low   X
0  27-Feb-15    10            1  x1
1  26-Feb-15    20            2  x2
2  25-Feb-15    50            3  x3
3  24-Feb-15   100            4  x4

df['X'] = df['High to Low'].rolling(2).sum().div(df['Open'])
print (df)
        Date  Open  High to Low     X
0  27-Feb-15    10            1   NaN
1  26-Feb-15    20            2  0.15
2  25-Feb-15    50            3  0.10
3  24-Feb-15   100            4  0.07
```

If necessary shift data add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['X'] = df['High to Low'].rolling(2).sum().div(df['Open']).shift(-1)
print (df)
        Date  Open  High to Low     X
0  27-Feb-15    10            1  0.15
1  26-Feb-15    20            2  0.10
2  25-Feb-15    50            3  0.07
3  24-Feb-15   100            4   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael ,this is exactly i wanted.

Comment: @sanuja - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)